# Atualização do Demoiselle para JEE7

Tags: java, demoiselle, jee

O framework Demoiselle tem incrementando em muito a produtividade aqui na empresa.
No entanto, ele esta sendo um limitador no uso de algumas novas tecnologias, especialmente relacionadas ao JEE7.

Meus projetos tirariam bastante proveito do JEE7, mas preciso escolher entre abrir mão do Demoiselle, ou usar as novidades. Alguém sabe se existe previsão de atualização do framework para compatibilidade com o JEE7?

Comment: Tales, pelo que entendi você deve buscar a comunidade do [Demoiselle](https://www.frameworkdemoiselle.gov.br/). Aqui é um site sem filiação à empresa para perguntas e respostas técnicas (é claro que você sempre pode cruzar com um desenvolvedor do Demoiselle no Stack Overflow, mas acredito que sua demanda é melhor resolvida diretamente com eles).

Comment: [Isto](https://www.frameworkdemoiselle.gov.br/forum/-/message_boards/message/204668?p_p_auth=4G3gPn2b&_19_threadId=204669) talvez explique como essa pergunta veio parar aqui. Tales, estou editando sua pergunta para se adequar ao formato deste site, mas pela natureza dela concordo com o @AnthonyAccioly que deve ser mais fácil conseguir a resposta diretamente no fórum do Demoiselle.

Comment: Muito obrigado, depois de enviar a pergunta me dei conta que não tinha adicionado as tags corretas.
Valeu!!

Comment: Essa atualização faz parte do planejamento para este ano. Foi feito um branch a partir da versão 2.5.x que está para ser lançada, mas os trabalhos de codificação ainda não se iniciaram de fato, pois os patrocinadores ainda estão fechando as questões de recursos humanos e de cronograma. Mas já podem ser feita contribuições, via pull-request no GitHub:   https://github.com/demoiselle/framework/tree/jee7

Answer (score 0):

A versão 3.0 do Demoiselle, compatível com JEE 7, foi disponibilizada em [fevereiro de 2017](https://github.com/demoiselle/framework/releases/tag/3.0.0).

- Mais informações em http://demoiselle.io/
- Aplicações de exemplo: https://github.com/demoiselle/example/tree/master/v3/